# Numeric Sorting of Numbers containing Vulgar Fractions

Tags: vb.net

Are there any sort algorithms that sort Integers and vulgar fractions?
For instance:    1  2¾  4 2½ etc.
Desired Result:  1  2½  2¾ 4 etc.

If no existing algorithms, is the best way to create a comparer in which the integer and vulgar fraction is split and each part sorted separately?

I have tried various methods, except the comparer method.

Comment: I'm presuming that these are stored as a string? i.e. `Dim A As String = "2¾"`? Can decimal fractions be mixed in too?

Comment: Yes, they are stored as a string.  Each number derives from a defined size such as:  2¾ x 4 x 6.  I split the input string on the 'x' to get 1, 2 or 3 parts depending on the size  definition.  Decimal fractions cannot be mixed in.

Comment: It strikes me that the easiest way to solve this is probably to use some kind of dictionary of the fractional characters to their decimal equivalents.  However, the main problem with that is that there are only a finite number defined - for example up to eigths but nothing more.  Also what unsimplified fractions, such as 6/8?

Comment: `dim fractions As String() = {"1", "2¾", "4", "2½"}.OrderBy(Function(s) s, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToArray()`

Comment: What's the reason you can't convert to a decimal in an OrderBy extension method?

Comment: Using StringComparer works if I have a list of, or string, of numbers.  However, these numbers come from sizes.. I have a generic list of 1, 2 and 3 part numbers in the form of WxLxH to be sorted.  Extracting and Converting the Fraction Portion to decimal, sorting and then converting the decimal back to a vulgar fraction will probably work. I am going to try it that way and see how it goes.  Thanks for the help and ideas.

Comment: So why don't you post your actual source of data? Why do ask a question related to a format that you don't really need or use?

Comment: Why would you need to convert back from decimal to fraction?  .OrderBy(Function(f) VulgarFractionToFloat(F)) will still preverse the original data type (fractions as a string)

Answer (score 2):

> hey are stored as a string. Each number derives from a defined size such as: 2¾ x 4 x 6.
>
> I have a generic list of 1, 2 and 3 part numbers in the form of WxLxH to be sorted.

Assuming the second statement means you have a list WLH stored as strings, the following code can sort that list.  Even if you have a different structure stored in the list, the following should give you an idea of how to sort it.

Note that the following sort mechanism is not very efficient in that it is repeatedly parsing the string values in the comparison function.

The function `ParseVulgarFraction` makes use of the [CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getunicodecategory?view=netframework-4.8) to determine whether the character is a digit or a fraction.  It also uses the [CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo.getnumericvalue?view=netframework-4.8) to retrieve the decimal value of the fraction.

To run this, create a new WinForm project and place a `DataGridView` on the form and add replace the form's code with the following. The `DataGridView` is just to display the sorted values.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
  Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Demo()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Demo()
    ' good source to copy fractions from: https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=FRACTION
    Const half As Char = "½"c : Const quart As Char = "¼"c : Const threeQuart As Char = "¾"c
    Const eighth As Char = "⅛"c : Const threeeighth As Char = "⅜"c : Const fiveeighth As Char = "⅝"c : Const seveneighth As Char = "⅞"c

    Dim dimensions As New List(Of String)

    dimensions.Add($"2{half} x 1{threeQuart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"2{half} x 1{quart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"2{half} x 1{threeeighth} x 5")
    dimensions.Add($"2{half} x 1{threeeighth} x 1")

    dimensions.Add($"1{half} x 1{threeQuart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"1{half} x 1{quart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"1{eighth} x 1{quart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"1{half} x 1{fiveeighth} x 5")
    dimensions.Add($"1{half} x 1{threeeighth} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"1{half} x 1{seveneighth} x 1")

    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{threeQuart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{quart} x 3")
    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{quart} x 2")
    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{quart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"12{eighth} x 1{quart} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{fiveeighth} x 5")
    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{threeeighth} x 1")
    dimensions.Add($"12{half} x 1{seveneighth} x 1")

    dimensions.Add($"{half} x 1{threeQuart} x 1")

    dimensions.Sort(New Comparison(Of String)(AddressOf WLHStringComparison))

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dimensions
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "WLH"
    DataGridView1.Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
  End Sub

  Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    e.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem.ToString
  End Sub

  Private Shared Function WLHStringComparison(x As String, y As String) As Int32
    Dim ret As Int32
    Dim xt As (w As Double, l As Double, h As Double) = GetWLHValues(x)
    Dim yt As (w As Double, l As Double, h As Double) = GetWLHValues(y)
    ret = xt.w.CompareTo(yt.w)
    If ret = 0 Then
      ret = xt.l.CompareTo(yt.l)
      If ret = 0 Then
        ret = xt.h.CompareTo(yt.h)
      End If
    End If
    Return ret
  End Function

  Private Shared Function GetWLHValues(wlh As String) As (w As Double, l As Double, h As Double)
    Dim ret As (w As Double, l As Double, h As Double)
    Dim parts As String() = wlh.Split("xX".ToCharArray(), 3)
    For i As Int32 = 0 To parts.Length - 1
      Dim val As Double = ParseVulgarFraction(parts(i))
      Select Case i
        Case 0 : ret.w = val
        Case 1 : ret.l = val
        Case 2 : ret.h = val
      End Select
    Next
    Return ret
  End Function

  Private Shared Function ParseVulgarFraction(value As String) As Double
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim fraction As Double = 0

    For Each c As Char In value
      Select Case CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)
        Case UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber
          sb.Append(c)
        Case UnicodeCategory.OtherNumber
          fraction = CharUnicodeInfo.GetNumericValue(c)
          Exit For ' stop parsing on 1st fraction
      End Select
    Next

    Dim returnValue As Double = 0
    ' parse the integer part if there is one
    If sb.Length > 0 Then returnValue = Double.Parse(sb.ToString())
    returnValue += fraction

    Return returnValue
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks TnTinMn.  Fortunately I don't have to sort often.